# Group list of strings by subparts of item

Tags: c#

Sorry for the ambiguous title...
I find explaining my issue difficult - let me know if you need to know more.

I've got a list that i'd like to be grouped by part of a string.
This string is also in the list.
This is the complete list, its not static, and will contain different values.

```
CookieMaker_TransportSettingsManual
CookieMaker_TransportSettingsParameters
Cookie_WrapperSettings
Cookie_WrapperSettingsManual
Cookie_WrapperSettingsParameters
Cookie_ProfileBendSettings
Cookie_ProfileBendSettingsParameters
Cookie_HopperSettings
Cookie_HopperSettingsManual
Cookie_HopperSettingsParameters
Cookie_CutterSettings
Cookie_CutterSettingsManual
Cookie_CutterSettingsParameters
General_SpeedSetting
General_SpeedSettingManual
General_SpeedSettingSettings
General_CalibrationSettings
General_CalibrationSettingsCalibration
Bonbon_Vertical
Bonbon_VerticalAligner
Bonbon_VerticalHopper
Bonbon_VerticalManual
Bonbon_VerticalTransporter
Bonbon_Horizontal
Bonbon_HorizontalHopper
Bonbon_HorizontalManual
Bonbon_HorizontalCookie
Bonbon_HorizontalTransporter
Bonbon_Bonbon
Bonbon_BonbonExhaust
Bonbon_BonbonManual
Bonbon_BonbonSection1
Bonbon_BonbonSection2
Bonbon_BonbonSection3
Bonbon_Compensator
Bonbon_CompensatorCarriage
Bonbon_CompensatorHopper
Bonbon_CompensatorManual
Bonbon_CollectingUnit
Bonbon_CollectingUnitManual
Bonbon_CollectingUnitTransporter
Bonbon_CollectingUnitTubeMaker
CookieMaker_TransportSettings
CookieMaker_TransportSettingsBonbon
CookieMaker_TransportSettingsPandora
```

The expected result would be a groups like so:

```
General_SpeedSetting
  ==> General_SpeedSettingManual
  ==> General_SpeedSettingSettings

Cookie_WrapperSettings
  ==> Cookie_WrapperSettingsManual
  ==> Cookie_WrapperSettingsParameters
```

The resulting datatype does not matter.
Also i don't mind linq.

Code / fiddle to get up and running quickly;

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inputString = "CookieMaker_TransportSettingsManual|CookieMaker_TransportSettingsParameters|Cookie_WrapperSettings|Cookie_WrapperSettingsManual|Cookie_WrapperSettingsParameters|Cookie_ProfileBendSettings|Cookie_ProfileBendSettingsParameters|Cookie_HopperSettings|Cookie_HopperSettingsManual|Cookie_HopperSettingsParameters|Cookie_CutterSettings|Cookie_CutterSettingsManual|Cookie_CutterSettingsParameters|General_SpeedSetting|General_SpeedSettingManual|General_SpeedSettingSettings|General_CalibrationSettings|General_CalibrationSettingsCalibration|Bonbon_Vertical|Bonbon_VerticalAligner|Bonbon_VerticalHopper|Bonbon_VerticalManual|Bonbon_VerticalTransporter|Bonbon_Horizontal|Bonbon_HorizontalHopper|Bonbon_HorizontalManual|Bonbon_HorizontalCookie|Bonbon_HorizontalTransporter|Bonbon_Bonbon|Bonbon_BonbonExhaust|Bonbon_BonbonManual|Bonbon_BonbonSection1|Bonbon_BonbonSection2|Bonbon_BonbonSection3|Bonbon_Compensator|Bonbon_CompensatorCarriage|Bonbon_CompensatorHopper|Bonbon_CompensatorManual|Bonbon_CollectingUnit|Bonbon_CollectingUnitManual|Bonbon_CollectingUnitTransporter|Bonbon_CollectingUnitTubeMaker|CookieMaker_TransportSettings|CookieMaker_TransportSettingsBonbon|CookieMaker_TransportSettingsPandora";
        var inputList = inputString.Split('|');
        
        var result = inputList; // Code here ;)
                        
        foreach(var r in result)
        { Console.WriteLine(r);}
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/neCUEL

Comment: What is the rule? Where is defined what the group keys are?

Comment: How do you know where to break the string for the groups? Why is the first group `General_SpeedSetting` and not `General` or `General_Speed`? You have to be able to give a simple rule that works in all cases.

Comment: Hi @TimSchmelter, unfortunately I do not know what the group keys are beforehand. These are actually screens and tabs on that screen, e.g. `CookieMaker_TransportSettingsManual` is a tab on the screen 'CookieMaker_TransportSettings'. The naming is mostly convention based, the name of the subject, then an underscore, and the the name of the screen, and the name of the panel/tab in that screen amended to the name. Therefore the grouping keys are in the list itself - which is why it makes it difficult to create a grouping.

Comment: Well, you need to have a rule of some sort.  Compare the three `General_SpeedSetting` strings to the two `CookieMaker_TransportSettings` strings.  I can't see a general rule that meets what I think you want.  If the two `CookieMaker_TransportSettings` strings started with a third heading (and that was consistent: screen name, tab name, tab name...), then it would be possible.  But you aren't following that rule

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Hi and thanks for taking the time to review my question. The order of the list is only there because when i produce the list i have an `OrderBy()` somewhere. I'm having a hard time explaining this, but for example the group key for `Bonbon_BonbonExhaust` would be `Bonbon_Bonbon`. In terms of 'rules' i'm guesing you could say that `Bonbon_Bonbon` would be the only string that is not referenced in any items in the rest of the list - so that would be something to look for although i'm a bit clueless how you would do that.

Comment: @Flydog57 Hiya, well unfortunately that is out of my control, because tbh i find the whole design of this also a bit confusing. I don't really have a way of determining the group keys beforehand - i only know that they're in the list.

Comment: Would this rule work: Find the longest common prefix between consecutive strings, where the boundary is a lower->upper case transition or an underscore to upper case transition.  The screen name is that prefix (which may eliminate one entry).  All subsequent strings with the same prefix get added to a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` that contains the prefix as the key and the list of matches as the list.  It would be tedious to code out the "longest common prefix" part, but otherwise not too hard. Of course, when the prefix is no longer present, you start over with a new prefix

Comment: @sommmen Why isn't there a CookieMaker_TransportSettings at the start? Every other group seems to start with the prefix on its own.

Comment: "I'm a bit clueless as how to do that." Until you know what you want, we can't hope to help you. Get someone else _who knows the data_ to come work through a whiteboard session, if you have to.

Comment: @Flydog57 Yeah that seems something that could work - There's also an answer that seems to do that

Comment: @Shanie that prefix is on the bottom, when generating the list there is no ordering. I do an `OrderBy` which is the only reason that the 'group prefix' if you will is at the top. Something is wrong i'm guessing with the ordering of the resulting list.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Hi Joel, I know what I want - i've described the desired output - i simply am not sure how to get there - and if i did we wouldn't be here now would we ;) I'm a bit on my own in this assignment for organisational reasons i won't get in to - so i'm interpreting things as i go. Anyways i get this question is a bit vague - i share that feeling, the posted answer now looks promising - anyways thanks for your attention.

Comment: @sommmen: did my answer help at all?  I think it answers your question exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
  
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(FILENAME).ToList();
             lines = lines.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

             List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
             Group group = new Group();
             groups.Add(group);
             group.basename = lines[0].Trim();
             List<List<string>> results = new List<List<string>>();
             for (int i = 2; i < lines.Count; i++)
             {
                 string line = lines[i].Trim();
                 if (!line.StartsWith(group.basename))
                 {
                     group = new Group();
                     groups.Add(group);
                     group.basename = line;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if(group.values == null) group.values = new List<string>();
                     group.values.Add(line.Substring(group.basename.Length));
                 }
             }
 
         }
    }
    public class Group
    {
        public string basename { get; set; }
        public List<string> values { get; set; }
    }

  
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm just done with work for the day so i'll be looking at this tomorrow, however when i plug the code into dotnetfiddle ( https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tribmw ) the output seems promising and what i was after. I need the full texts in the values list - but that is a minor detail. If i understand the code right, this does mean i need the list to be fully ordered in order for this to work right? that is not a problem i think.

Comment: Yes,  That is why I sorted the list : lines = lines.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

Comment: Some people believe in writing software from top down, others believe in bottom up.  I work from both ends of the candle. Often you have to start writing test code before you come up with an optimum solution. In this case I know the algorthm that is required. The difficult part of this problem is determining where one group starts and the next group begins. I know my splitting criteria is not perfect, but it is a good start and may need to change. The rest or the code is pretty solid.  A lot of people who may comments above I know very well and we often disagree. My solution has only one loop.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
                        
    public class Program
    {
        static List<string> myList = new List<string>(){
            "CookieMaker_TransportSettingsManual",
            "CookieMaker_TransportSettingsParameters",
            "Cookie_WrapperSettings",
            "Cookie_WrapperSettingsManual",
            "Cookie_WrapperSettingsParameters",
            "Cookie_ProfileBendSettings",
            "Cookie_ProfileBendSettingsParameters",
            "Cookie_HopperSettings",
            "Cookie_HopperSettingsManual",
            "Cookie_HopperSettingsParameters",
            "Cookie_CutterSettings",
            "Cookie_CutterSettingsManual",
            "Cookie_CutterSettingsParameters",
            "General_SpeedSetting",
            "General_SpeedSettingManual",
            "General_SpeedSettingSettings",
            "General_CalibrationSettings",
            "General_CalibrationSettingsCalibration",
            "Bonbon_Vertical",
            "Bonbon_VerticalAligner",
            "Bonbon_VerticalHopper",
            "Bonbon_VerticalManual",
            "Bonbon_VerticalTransporter",
            "Bonbon_Horizontal",
            "Bonbon_HorizontalHopper",
            "Bonbon_HorizontalManual",
            "Bonbon_HorizontalCookie",
            "Bonbon_HorizontalTransporter",
            "Bonbon_Bonbon",
            "Bonbon_BonbonExhaust",
            "Bonbon_BonbonManual",
            "Bonbon_BonbonSection1",
            "Bonbon_BonbonSection2",
            "Bonbon_BonbonSection3",
            "Bonbon_Compensator",
            "Bonbon_CompensatorCarriage",
            "Bonbon_CompensatorHopper",
            "Bonbon_CompensatorManual",
            "Bonbon_CollectingUnit",
            "Bonbon_CollectingUnitManual",
            "Bonbon_CollectingUnitTransporter",
            "Bonbon_CollectingUnitTubeMaker",
            "CookieMaker_TransportSettings",
            "CookieMaker_TransportSettingsBonbon",
            "CookieMaker_TransportSettingsPandora"
        };
        
        static Dictionary<string, List<string>> results = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------//
        
        public static void Main()
        {
            
            var orderedList = myList.OrderBy(i=>i).ToList();    
            
            int i = 0;      
            while(i < myList.Count){
            
                var prefix = orderedList[i];
                
                results[prefix] = new List<string>();
                
                if(++i >= orderedList.Count) break;
                            
                while(orderedList[i].StartsWith(prefix)){
                        
                    results[prefix].Add(orderedList[i]);
                    i++;
                    
                    if(i >= orderedList.Count) {                    
                        Print();
                        return;
                    }
                    
                }//while
                
            }//while
            
            Print();
            
        }//main
        
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------//
        
        private static void Print(){
            foreach (string prefix in results.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Prefix =>{prefix} - {results[prefix].Count}");
                    foreach (string result in results[prefix])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($" ======>{result}");
                    }//foreach;
            }//foreach
        }//Print
        

    }//Cls
```

Fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/GTI4vV

Comment: Hi shanie! thanks for your answer, I like the verbosity and the fact that you provided a dotnetfiddle for me. jdweng's answer was first and both answers operator on the same principle, so i'll accept that answer.

Comment: @sommmen OK, no worries

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you accepted a solution that pre-sorted the items.  When I tried that, the `Bonbon` sections got terribly messed up.

My solution is a bit hacky - to get this to work the way I think you want it took a lot of special cases (and fixing off-by-one issues).

The code takes care of this kind of pattern:

```
CookieMaker_TransportSettingsManual
CookieMaker_TransportSettingsParameters
```

extracting *CookieMaker_TransportSettings* and putting both entries under it.  It also copes with the fact that you have CookieMaker_TransportSettings at the beginning and the end of the file.

It also handles this:

```
Bonbon_BonbonSection1
Bonbon_BonbonSection2
Bonbon_BonbonSection3
```

Figuring that you want the three of those to be part of the `Bonbon_Bonbon` section and not a new `Bonbon_BonbonSection` section with three entries (1, 2 and 3).

It also deals with all the Cookie** and Bonbon** sections.

Here's the main code:

```
 //get all the strings from somewhere 
 var inputStrings = File.ReadAllLines("DataFile.txt");

 string lastTitle = null;
 var results = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
 string veryLastItem = string.Empty;

 var currentItems = new List<string>();
 for (var i = 0; i < inputStrings.Length - 1; ++i)
 {
     var commonPrefix = FindLongestCommonPrefix(inputStrings[i], inputStrings[i + 1]);
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(commonPrefix) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastTitle) && commonPrefix != lastTitle))
     {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastTitle))
         {
             throw new Exception("This isn't going to work - you need to have at least two common things in a row");
         }
         if (inputStrings[i].StartsWith(lastTitle) && inputStrings[i] != lastTitle)
         {
             currentItems.Add(inputStrings[i]);
         }
         AddResultsToDictionary(results, lastTitle, currentItems);
         currentItems = new List<string>();
     }

     if (commonPrefix != inputStrings[i] &&
         ((commonPrefix == lastTitle && commonPrefix != inputStrings[i]) ||
          (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(commonPrefix) && inputStrings[i].StartsWith(commonPrefix))))
     {
         currentItems.Add(inputStrings[i]);
     }

     lastTitle = commonPrefix;
     veryLastItem = inputStrings[i + 1];
 }

 //ok, we're out of the loop:
 //add the last item to the current list
 currentItems.Add(veryLastItem);

 //and add the last set of items to the dictionary
 if (lastTitle != null)
 {
     AddResultsToDictionary(results, lastTitle, currentItems);
 }

 foreach (var result in results)
 {
     Debug.WriteLine(result.Key);
     foreach (var item in result.Value)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine($"  ==> {item}");
     }
 }

 void AddResultsToDictionary(Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary, string s, List<string> list)
 {
     if (dictionary.TryGetValue(s, out var existingList))
     {
         existingList.AddRange(list);
     }
     else
     {
         dictionary.Add(s, list);
     }
 }
```

}

And it calls this function to determine the section headings:

```
private string FindLongestCommonPrefix(string s1, string s2)
{
    var minLen = Math.Min(s1.Length, s2.Length);
    for (var i = 0; i < minLen; ++i)
    {
        if (s1[i] != s2[i])
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                //if the common part is not s1, we need to find the last place where the following
                //   the last letter of the common part is a lower case letter followed by either
                //   an underscore or a capital letter
                if (i == s1.Length)
                {
                    return s1;
                }

                if (s1[i] == '_' || s1[i - 1] == '_' || s2[i] == '_' || s2[i - 1] == '_')
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }

                for (var j = i; j > 0; --j)
                {
                    if (char.IsLower(s1[j-1]) && (char.IsUpper(s1[j]) /*|| s1[j] == '_'*/))
                    {
                        return s1.Substring(0, j);
                    }
                }
                //I shouldn't get here, but, if I do
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
    //otherwise
    return s1.Substring(0, minLen);
}
```

The result ends up looking like:

```
CookieMaker_TransportSettings
  ==> CookieMaker_TransportSettingsManual
  ==> CookieMaker_TransportSettingsParameters
  ==> CookieMaker_TransportSettingsBonbon
  ==> CookieMaker_TransportSettingsPandora
Cookie_WrapperSettings
  ==> Cookie_WrapperSettingsManual
  ==> Cookie_WrapperSettingsParameters
Cookie_ProfileBendSettings
  ==> Cookie_ProfileBendSettingsParameters
Cookie_HopperSettings
  ==> Cookie_HopperSettingsManual
  ==> Cookie_HopperSettingsParameters
Cookie_CutterSettings
  ==> Cookie_CutterSettingsManual
  ==> Cookie_CutterSettingsParameters
General_SpeedSetting
  ==> General_SpeedSettingManual
  ==> General_SpeedSettingSettings
General_CalibrationSettings
  ==> General_CalibrationSettingsCalibration
Bonbon_Vertical
  ==> Bonbon_VerticalAligner
  ==> Bonbon_VerticalHopper
  ==> Bonbon_VerticalManual
  ==> Bonbon_VerticalTransporter
Bonbon_Horizontal
  ==> Bonbon_HorizontalHopper
  ==> Bonbon_HorizontalManual
  ==> Bonbon_HorizontalCookie
  ==> Bonbon_HorizontalTransporter
Bonbon_Bonbon
  ==> Bonbon_BonbonExhaust
  ==> Bonbon_BonbonManual
  ==> Bonbon_BonbonSection1
  ==> Bonbon_BonbonSection2
  ==> Bonbon_BonbonSection3
Bonbon_Compensator
  ==> Bonbon_CompensatorCarriage
  ==> Bonbon_CompensatorHopper
  ==> Bonbon_CompensatorManual
Bonbon_CollectingUnit
  ==> Bonbon_CollectingUnitManual
  ==> Bonbon_CollectingUnitTransporter
  ==> Bonbon_CollectingUnitTubeMaker
```

Comment: Hiya, thanks for putting this much effort in a random stranger's question. Its much appreciated. This solution seems more robuust than a ordered approach. I'm not sure why when you took that approach the `Bonbon` section got messed up as the other answers seem to work like they should (for this particular set). Anyhow the solution I have now works but i'm sure itll break at some point (I can imagine if the headers have the same string length..) I may just revisit this then. Again thanks for the effort!